# Making jQuery functions delay and load at the same rate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get this jQuery function working and have tried everything to the best of my knowledge, just can't seem to get the result I want.

I have 3 'loading' skill set bars, and they all fire off at the same speed of 2000, however it is counting the time it takes to get to their final point. The two highest values will animate way before a really low one, but they all end at their final points at the same. I want them to start at the same time instead.

I would also like to delay the animations for about 3-4seconds since I'm assuming that's how long it will take a user to scroll to them.

**HTML Code for 1 bar**

```
<div class="bar" data-percent="75%">
    <div class="tag" style="background: #27ae60;">
    <span>CSS</span>
  </div>
  <div class="load" style="background-color: #2ecc71;"></div>
  <div class="skill-bar-percent">75%</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('.bar').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.load').animate({
      width:$(this).attr('data-percent')}, 2000);
  });
});
```

and of course a [JS Fiddle[(http://jsfiddle.net/w2vb41g4/7/)

Is there a simple way around this? I have tried to use `.delay()` throughout the function but it is to no success. I have also tried setting a separate `.setTimeout()` function which also has no effect.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Actually, they all start at the same time, the issue is that they are hidden behind the title, and as they last the same amount of time, you don't see the shortest one until a bit later (the time that it takes to go behind the title). One possible solution for this: position the bars right where the title ends, then you'll see all the animations starting at the same time

Comment: I see that now, that makes sense, any idea on the delay?  Updated the fiddle.

Comment: the delay issue is that you are using `setTimeout` with a function but not specific delay. Just change your code to add the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in the comments:

- The delay is simple: just add a time to the `setTimeout` that you use. For example, add 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds):

  ```
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.bar').each(function(){
      $(this).find('.load').animate({
        width: $(this).attr('data-percent') }, 2000);
    });
  }, 2000);
  ```
- For the bars starting at the same time, just place them right after the title:

  ```
  .bar{ /* SKILL BAR */
    position: relative;
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
      overflow:hidden;
  }

  .load{ /* LOADING BAR */
    width: 0;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      left:110px;
  }
  ```

  (there are some other cosmetic changes in CSS, they don't affect the functionality, just to make it look better. See them on the fiddle below)

You can see it working on an update of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w2vb41g4/14/

---

***Update***: This is the code that makes it grow to the right place (taking into account the 110px):

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.bar').each(function () {
        $(this).find('.load').each(function () {
            $(this).animate({
                width: ($(this).parent().width() - 110) * $(this).parent().attr('data-percent') / 100
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Actually, you'll need to make an additional change: right now the load bar overflows and then the percentage covered is higher than the one specified in the `data-percent`. You should make it grow to `data-percent` minus the 110px that they were moved to the right

Comment: This is great, except the fact that the percentages are off due to the `left:110px`.  With that being said, how would you write the `100% - 110px`?

Comment: As a quick and dirty solution: http://jsfiddle.net/w2vb41g4/24/ (notice how I replace the values of `data-percent` removing the % symbol, if you want to leave them the same, you'll have to use `.replace("%","")`)

Comment: Ahh I see, this is excellent. I thought I may have needed something with a little bit of concatenation, thanks for the fast response and all the help!